# Hide link based on Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-roles

Im new to asp.mvc. I'm trying to develop a portal to maintain employee data. In my system only "Manager" has the rigths to create employee. How do I enable the link when manager log in and disable when employee log in. Thanks

My View

```
@model IEnumerable<SealManagementPortal_3._0.Models.VOC_CUSTODIAN>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Custodians";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GridData", "Custodian")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Agent ID', 'Branch', 'Unique ID', 'Custodian Name', /*'NRIC No', 'E-Mail', 'Contact No', 'Mobile No',*/'Role', 'Details', 'Edit', 'Delete'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Agent ID', index: '', width: 10, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Branch', index: '', width: 10, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Unique ID', index: '', width: 10, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Custodian Name', index: '', width: 10, align: 'left' },                
                {name: 'Role', index: '', width: 10, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Details', index: '', width: 5, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Edit', index: '', width: 5, align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Delete', index: '', width: 5, align: 'left'}],
            pager: jQuery('#pager2'),
            rowNum: 10,                
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            autowidth: true,
            caption: 'Custodians List'
        });
    }); 
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table id="list2" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use roles. The first **and most important thing** is to decorate the controller action that is supposed to perform the update with the `Authorize` attribute and specify the correct roles that the user must posses in order to access this controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Managers")]
public ActionResult Create(Employee emp)
{
    ...
}
```

Once everything is secure on the server you could do cosmetics in the view and show the link only if the user is in the `Managers` role:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Managers"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Create employee", "Create")
}
```

You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) for more information about forms authentication and roles.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the repetition of "Managers" in the template? I would like to have role management in one place and the Authorize attribute is very fine with me. Can I somehow define an HtmlHelper that accesses the content of the attribute?