# Authorization in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have a menu in web site. I want to access this for every role .

For example : i have 3 role that Role1 have access to personnel, referred, visit menu, and role2 have access to personnel, diet menu , and role3 have full access.

I created a static class that set value when user login in site. and use this class property for show/hide menu. but change this value when a nother user is login in site.

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static string UserName { get; set; }
    public static string Image { get; set; }

    public static bool IsAuthorizePersonnel { get; set; }
    public static bool IsAuthorizeReferred { get; set; }
    public static bool IsAuthorizeDiet { get; set; }
    public static bool IsAuthorizeVisit { get; set; }
 }
```

How do i set access for menu ?

Answer (score 1):

The static class is changing when new users login because ASP.NET handles multiple requests/clients in the same App domain, which means they share static classes/properties.

In order to make something like this work you would need to cache the information either via session state or a user keyed memory cache (such as Redis).

Alternatively, Asp.Net simple membership does have role support, so you could also consider creating the `IsX` properties as wrappers around role checks.

See the following articles for some examples:

- http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/security/16-adding-security-and-membership
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb%28v=vs.140%29.aspx
- [Hide link based on Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078423/asp-mvc-hide-link-based-on-role)

Comment: Thanks, i use role and set user in role. but i want to get property value of user in login view and use this value in another view

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a single instance of the class which is used for all users in the site. Due to it being a static class.

You should create an instance-per-user class. Which you could place inside the cache under fi username.

Comment: Thanks, when a created instance-per-user class, how do i use this in another view?